# stats.stackexchange hangs computer when loading Web-font Tex/math/italic

Tags: bug, status-norepro, statistics, latex, math-se

On a Vista 32 bit and a Windows 7 64 bit computer running the latest Firefox, stats.stackexchange sometimes completely blocks the computer when loading the web-font Tex/math/italic part for the first time.

The mouse freezes as well. A little waiting and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> solves the problem, but it's highly annoying. I thought at first it was my computer, but I have it every time now and on two different computers.

Does anybody else have this problem?

Comment: when you say "latest Firefox" do you mean 4.0 beta or the released version?

Comment: @Jeff Atwood : Firefox 3.6.10 I run.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @PeterMortensen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce this in Firefox 3.6.10 ..

[Interpreting 2D correspondence analysis plots](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3270/interpreting-2d-correspondence-analysis-plots)

[image: firefox 3.6.10 stats screenshot]

Have you tried running Firefox in SAFE MODE, to ensure that it's not some rogue or poorly written plugin? That's usually the case with Firefox problems.